# Additional Drivers missing on a fresh Debian 10 + XFCE install

Tags: debian, xfce

How can I get the "Additional Drivers" tab to show up in Settings? This is all I see?

I know it is using non-free drivers, like for my wifi, because I had to use the firmware netinstall when it complained that it needed non-free.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the "Additional Drivers" tab of the `software-properties-gtk` tool is an Ubuntu thing and doesn't exist in Debian (see https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/software-properties-gtk and its dependency to [ubuntu-drivers-common](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/ubuntu-drivers-common)).

If you know what you're looking for, you can use `synaptic` and browse the "non-free" sections.

[image]